# Shortcut to find and preview all PDFs in folder

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, automation, shortcuts, automator

On MacOS, is there a way to add a shortcut that will quickly search for all PDFs in a selected folder? More specifically, I'd like a shortcut* that, when a folder is selected in Finder, will search that folder and return all the PDF files contained in that folder.

My thinking is that this could be done using either a script or the Mac Automator App. My use case is the following: I have folders containing multiple PDFs in different subdirectories, and it is time-consuming to individually click through all of these subddirectories to preview and compare each PDF.

*shortcut = keyboard shortcut, right-click option, service, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't need a shortcut. It is so easy to do in Finder.

1. Navigate to the folder;
2. Click the search icon at the top of the window;
3. Type `PDF`; and
4. Select `PDF Document` in the drop down.

You can condense steps 3 and 4 to just:

3. Type `kind:PDF` (more keystrokes, less clicks)

Having got your list of all PDFs:

- Optionally add extra columns.
- Sort by selecting a column header.